# Destroy player GameObject

Tags: unity

I'm doing a game in Unity and I have a question regarding the destruction of my player object. 
Currently I'm destroying the player with

```
    public void Die()
{
    isDead = true;
    GetComponent<ScoreController>().SetEndLevelScore();
    GetComponent<ScoreController>().SetTotalScore();
    //ParticleSystem intantiatedParticle = Instantiate(deathParticle, transform.position, transform.rotation) as ParticleSystem;
    Debug.Log("Removing camera parent");
    Camera.main.transform.parent = null;
    sceneLoader.GetComponent<SceneLoad>().StartCoroutine("LoadScoreScreenAfterDelay");
    Debug.Log("Destroying player object");
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Player object destroyed");
}
```

Now this works when I use it in the editor: the player is destroyed, the main camera shows the scene for a few seconds and then the scene changes to the score scene. As you can see:[image]

However, this is not working as it should when I'm playing the game from the built version. In this case the player GameObject model is still there, as shown here:[image]

This also happens if I use `gameObject.SetActive(false);` instead.

Anybody can tell me why it's not working on the built game but it is on the editor? Thanks!

P.S. : This is the log from the built version after health reaches 0:

```
Health <= 0
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:333)

(Filename: Assets/03-Scripts/PlayerController.cs Line: 333)

Current level score setted in PlayerPrefs
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ScoreController:SetEndLevelScore() (at Assets\03-Scripts\ScoreController.cs:131)
PlayerController:Die() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:371)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: Assets/03-Scripts/ScoreController.cs Line: 131)

Total score setted in PlayerPrefs
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ScoreController:SetTotalScore() (at Assets\03-Scripts\ScoreController.cs:143)
PlayerController:Die() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:372)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: Assets/03-Scripts/ScoreController.cs Line: 143)

Removing camera parent
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Die() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:374)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: Assets/03-Scripts/PlayerController.cs Line: 374)

Started wait time after death
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoadScoreScreenAfterDelay>d__2:MoveNext() (at Assets\03-Scripts\SceneLoad.cs:16)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\Coroutines.cs:17)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged(String, Object)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String, Object) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\MonoBehaviour.bindings.cs:79)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\MonoBehaviour.bindings.cs:67)
PlayerController:Die() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:376)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: Assets/03-Scripts/SceneLoad.cs Line: 16)

Destroying player object
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Die() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:377)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: Assets/03-Scripts/PlayerController.cs Line: 377)

Player object destroyed
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Die() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:379)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: Assets/03-Scripts/PlayerController.cs Line: 379)
```

And this is the log in the built version:

```
Health <= 0
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Update() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:333)

(Filename: C:/Users/Hector/GitHub/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Assets/03-Scripts/PlayerController.cs Line: 333)

Current level score setted in PlayerPrefs
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ScoreController:SetEndLevelScore() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\ScoreController.cs:131)
PlayerController:Die() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:371)
PlayerController:Update() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: C:/Users/Hector/GitHub/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Assets/03-Scripts/ScoreController.cs Line: 131)

Total score setted in PlayerPrefs
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ScoreController:SetTotalScore() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\ScoreController.cs:143)
PlayerController:Die() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:372)
PlayerController:Update() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: C:/Users/Hector/GitHub/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Assets/03-Scripts/ScoreController.cs Line: 143)

Removing camera parent
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Die() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:374)
PlayerController:Update() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: C:/Users/Hector/GitHub/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Assets/03-Scripts/PlayerController.cs Line: 374)

Started wait time after death
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<LoadScoreScreenAfterDelay>d__2:MoveNext() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\SceneLoad.cs:16)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged(String, Object)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String, Object)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String)
PlayerController:Die() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:376)
PlayerController:Update() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: C:/Users/Hector/GitHub/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Assets/03-Scripts/SceneLoad.cs Line: 16)

Destroying player object
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Die() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:377)
PlayerController:Update() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: C:/Users/Hector/GitHub/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Assets/03-Scripts/PlayerController.cs Line: 377)

Player object destroyed
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Die() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:379)
PlayerController:Update() (at C:\Users\Hector\GitHub\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Shapeshifting Racing 3D\Assets\03-Scripts\PlayerController.cs:334)

(Filename: C:/Users/Hector/GitHub/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Shapeshifting Racing 3D/Assets/03-Scripts/PlayerController.cs Line: 379)
```

Comment: This likely means your code is throwing an exception midway through, before it destroys the player, aborting execution of your method so it never gets to that step. Try attaching a debugger so you can catch the exception and investigate what code is causing it.

Comment: I've checked and there isn't any exception before destroying the player. It looks like the object destruction is doing something different in the built version.

Comment: If a core element like Destroy had different behaviour in a build, trust me, you'd have heard about it by now. This problem is almost certainly elsewhere in your code. Try aetting a breakpoint or adding logging at each step of your player death process, so you can see exactly which path the code takes and where it deviates from the editor behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly. I didn't mean that Destroy is doing anything different, I meant that the destruction of the player has a different effect on something in the built version. Mostly because looks like in the built version everything freezes before going to the next scene, but in the editor it doesn't (for example, the lasers keep moving).

Comment: What did you find when you tried stepping through with a debugger, or logging each step as I recommended above?

Comment: The game continued as it should, it continued normally and after the delay time was over it went to the score screen. No exceptions or noticeable errors, but the screen froze after the Destroy(gameObject).

Comment: It sounds like you didn't do what I asked you to. We won't be able to help you with the information you've shared so far. Please step through your program with the debugger or log every single step so that you can verify the exact moment where the code does something different in build than it does in editor. Then you can edit your question to show us that part of your code and the debugging results you've gotten so far.

Comment: I've tried both debugging step by step after player health reaches 0 untill the score scene is loaded and logging the steps both in the editor and the built versions. There are no differences that I could see. If you want I can post the logs, should I post only what happens when health reaches 0 for both versions? Or you need everything until score screen is loaded?

Comment: Hard to say, since you've shown us only three lines of code — we'd have a hard time guessing what interesting things your program might do outside those lines. Everything leading up to and just after destruction of the player character object should be a good starting point.

Comment: Could you tell me how to upload the logs? I believe they are too long to post them here (about 600-700 lines since the player health raches 0 until score scene is loaded, each). Also I've updated my post with all the code oh the player death function, which is called whenever it's health reaches 0.

Comment: It will suffice to just document whether "Removing camera parent" "Destroying player object" and "Player object destroyed" appear in your log.

Comment: I've added the logs for both versions to the main post.

Comment: Ok, I've found the issue. The camera was attached to the player and when the player died I was freeing it with Camera.main.transform.parent = null;. This was causing a different behaviour in build and in the editor versions. If I use a camera not attached to the player with a script following it instead it works.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! Want to document it as an Answer below to help future users who run into a similar problem?

Comment: Done, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the issue was happening when changing the main camera parent to null.
I have several cameras attached to the player but only one is active. Before, I was trying to get the camera in use and setting its parent to null before destroying the player GameObject, using `Camera.main.transform.parent = null;`.

Now I set all the cameras parents to null instead and works.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMCAMERAS; ++i)
{
    cameras[i].transform.parent = null;
}
```

Also works if I detach the cameras from the player and make them move with a script.

Still I find it a bit strange that `Camera.main.transform.parent = null;` worked in the editor but not on the built version.